# Setting UIScrollView's minimumZoomScale changes UIImageView's frame origin

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I'm trying to implement a simple control to allow the user to zoom in and out of an image. I have a UIImageView inside a UIScrollView. Additionally, I would like to prevent the user from zooming out so much that either the width or height of the image is smaller than the scroll view's size. Here is where the problem lies: when I set the minimumZoomScale to the appropriate size, the image appears in a weird location. Here's my code to configure the scroll view and image view:

```
- (void)openNewImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    _originalImage = image;

    // Reset scroll view's zoom scales
    // (must be reset before setting the image to the image view)
    self.imageScrollView.zoomScale = 1.0f;
    self.imageScrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.01f;

    // Set scroll view's content size to allow scrolling
    self.imageScrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
    self.imageScrollView.contentSize = image.size;

    // Set image and resize image view to image size
    self.imageView.image = _originalImage;
    self.imageView.frame =
        CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, image.size.width, image.size.height);

    [self.imageScrollView zoomToRect:self.imageView.frame animated:YES];
    self.imageScrollView.minimumZoomScale = self.imageScrollView.zoomScale;
}
```

The last line is causing problems because if I comment it out, things appear where they should, but then the user can zoom out too much. While trying to debug the problem, I found that the last line causes the image view's frame origin to change to very small negative numbers, like -1.11015e-06 rather than just 0. If I comment out the last line, the image view's frame origin is 0. I wonder if somehow this is causing problems, although that small negative number is virtually 0.